# SQL Query to get missing staff member

Tags: sql, sybase

I have following problem to find out if a User with a specific job role is missing in one project:

Table 1:

```
ID | Project_ID
---+------------
1  | 11A
1  | 11B
1  | 11C
2  | 12B
2  | 12C
3  | 13A
3  | 13C
```

Table 2:

```
Project_ID   | JobRole_ID
-------------+------------
11A          | A
11B          | B
11C          | C
12B          | B
12C          | C
13A          | A
13C          | C
```

Table 3:

```
JobRole_ID | JobRole
-----------+---------
A          | Manager
B          | Project Leader
C          | Project Assistent
```

For each project jobrole A,B and C are required (Table 3). Table 2 only contains added JobRoles, not missing ones.

What i expect is:

```
ID | JobRole
---+---------
1  | Manager
2  | NULL
3  | Manager
```

Please help me! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You want to find Projects where exists a JobRole which is not tied to this particular project.

From top of my head:

```
--try to find projects
SELECT
    T1.Id
FROM 
    Table1 AS T1
WHERE 
    --with at least one role
    EXISTS(
        SELECT
            *
        FROM 
            Table3 AS T3
        WHERE 
            --where mapping does not exist
            NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                    Table2 AS T2
                WHERE 
                    T2.Project_ID = T1.Project_ID AND 
                    T2.JobRole_ID = T3.JobRole_ID
            )
    )
```

**EDIT:**

Could this be what you want? If not, could you please give us more details?

```
SELECT
    T1.Id, T3.JobRole_ID 
FROM 
    Table1 AS T1 LEFT JOIN
    Table2 AS T2 ON T2.Project_ID = T1.Project_ID LEFT JOIN
    Table3 AS T3 ON T3.JobRole_ID = T2.JobRole_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method:

```
select p.*, j.*
from projects p cross join
     jobroles j left join
     projectjobs pj
     on p.project_id = pj.project_id and
        j.jobrole_id = pj.jobrole_id
where pj.project_id is null;
```

It generates a list of all projects and all jobs (using the `cross join`).  Then, using the `left join` and `where` clause, it filters out the ones that exist.

EDIT:

You can try with comma:

```
select p.*, j.*
from projects p,
     jobroles j left join
     projectjobs pj
     on p.project_id = pj.project_id and
        j.jobrole_id = pj.jobrole_id
where pj.project_id is null;
```

But this may not work because of the semantics of how the comma is parsed in the `from` clause.  You might need a subquery:

```
select xpj.*
from (select p.*, j.*
      from projects p, jobroles j
     ) xpj left join
     projectjobs pj
     on xpj.project_id = pj.project_id and
        xpj.jobrole_id = pj.jobrole_id
where pj.project_id is null;
```

Comment: The downside (or upside if you need missing roles) of this query is that it will return multiple rows if multiple JobRoles are missing. It could be easily fixed with `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: @KasparsOzols . . . This form of the query will not return duplicates (unlss `projects` or `jobroles` have duplicates).  As for why Sybase ASE doesn't understand the query, I don't know.  This is ANSI standard SQL syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made a mistake, please take a look again at my definition. thx Cross Joins in Sybase work this way "From projects p, jobroles j"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated requirements this should work, although I'm sure it can be simplified.

```
select a.ID, b.JobRole 
from (
    select * from Table1, table3 where JobRole_ID = 'A'
) a left join (
    select t1.id, t3.jobrole
    from  table1 t1 
    left join table2 t2 on t2.project_id = t1.project_id 
    left join table3 t3 on t3.jobrole_id = t2.jobrole_id 
) b on a.id = b.id and a.jobrole = b.jobrole
group by a.ID, b.JobRole
```

Comment: OP states that all 3 JobRoles are required.

Comment: @KasparsOzols The question ends with: _Now i want to know the ID of table 1 where Jobrole 'A' is missing._ which is exactly what this query answers. Maybe I'm interpreting it too narrowly though. The OP specifies the missing A though, not the missing B for Project 13.

Comment: @matd I thought this was what you wanted, but if it isn't could you describe what output you expect/want?

Comment: @KasparsOzols I made a mistake in my definition. Please take a look again. thx

Comment: @jpw I made a mistake in my definition, please take a look again for help thx

Comment: @matd I'm looking at your desired output but I don't understand what it means; why is is 1:manager, 2:null, 3:manager when it looks like 1 isn't missing any role, 2 is missing A and 3 is missing B. Could you clarify it?

Comment: @jpw I want to get all IDs from List 1 where A is included and is missing (NULL). B and C should be ignored if they are included or not. You know what i mean?

Comment: @matd I think I understand. I've changed my answer.

Comment: @jpw Great, that works!!! What has to be done if there multiple entries for e.g. 2 Managers at 1 Project (1 of them is Primary, the other secondary) and i want to get both?

Comment: @matd Sorry, I don't know how to do that.